I want to reflect the results of a pay-as-you-go payment in Run Payments with Stripe in firestore
I am using basic html and javascript.I'm a beginner programmer.
I am currently working on a program that uses Stripe to process payments on a pay-as-you-go basis and reflect the results in Firestore. However, we are facing the following issue:
Problem Description:
I have set up a webhook in Firebase Functions, but I am getting the following error log:

❗️[Error]: Webhook handler for Stripe event [] of type [checkout.session.completed] failed: User not found!

my functions code

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports\['ext-firestore-stripe-payments-handleWebhookEvents'\] = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) =\> {
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.secret_key);

let event;

try {
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
req.rawBody,
req.headers\['stripe-signature'\],
functions.config().stripe.webhook_sub_secret
);
} catch (err) {
console.log(err);
return res.sendStatus(400);
}

if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
const session = event.data.object;
const userId = session.client_reference_id;
const incrementValue = 10;

      const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId);
    
      return userRef.update({
          clickCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(incrementValue)
      }).then(() => {
          return res.status(200).send('Success');
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.error('Firestore Error', error);
          return res.status(500).send('Error');
      });

}

res.status(200).end();
});

I checked the webhook request in the Stripe dashboard, and it indeed does not contain a Firebase Auth user ID.
On the Stripe dashboard, I have confirmed the payment_intent.succeeded and checkout.session.completed events.
Question:
How can I get Firestore to update correctly after a payment is completed in Stripe?
My goal is for the user's Firestore document to reflect the purchase information once the purchase is completed. I would appreciate any specific implementation advice or solutions you can provide.
Thank you for reading my poor English. Best regards.
